Google Sheet Script 2 on edit function #NUM! error
I get #NUM! error, if I edit the cells in row 2 and 3. The error will be in the corresponding row below that certain edited cell.
Here is the script:
Main:
function onEdit(e) {
   doFirstThing_(e);
   doSecondThing_(e);
}

Then the first function
// Define the original quantities of the ingredients for the recipe
var originalQuantitiesFirst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1];  // Couscous, Teff, Fig, Date, Hamburg
    
function doFirstThing_(e) {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  
  // Get the sheet named 'Valencia'
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Valencia');
  
  // Check if the edited cell is in the 'Quantity' column (Column B, D, F, H, or J in this case)
  if (["B3", "D3", "F3", "H3", "J3", "F2"].includes(e.range.getA1Notation())) {
    // Get the new quantity
    var newQuantity = e.value;
  
    // Log the new quantity
    console.log('New quantity in doFirstThing_: ' + newQuantity);
     
    // Calculate the ratio of new quantity to original quantity of the changed ingredient
    var ingredientIndex = ["B3", "D3", "F3", "H3", "J3", "F2"].indexOf(e.range.getA1Notation());
    var ratio = newQuantity / originalQuantitiesFirst[ingredientIndex];
        
    // Define the cells with the quantities
    var quantityCells = ["B3", "D3", "F3", "H3", "J3", "F2"];
        
    // Loop through each quantity cell
    for (var i = 0; i < quantityCells.length; i++) {
      // Update the quantity based on the ratio and the original quantity
      var newQuantity = originalQuantitiesFirst[i] * ratio;
          
      // Update the cell with the new quantity
      sheet.getRange(quantityCells[i]).setValue(newQuantity);
    }
  }
}

Last function:
// Define the original quantities of the ingredients for all recipes
var originalQuantities = [[1, 3, 6, 4, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1], [5, 3, 2, 3, 1], [4, 5, 1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 4, 4, 1]];  // Stew, Nutmeg, Dough, Vegetables, Bread, Scorpion, Sauce, Stew, Fig, Sugar, Oil, Dough, Agent, Date, Sugar, Liquor, Nutmeg, Pickle, Meat, Bread
    
function doSecondThing_(e) {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      
  // Check if the edited cell is in the 'Quantity' column (Column B, D, F, H, or J in this case)
  // and the sheet is 'Valencia'
  if ([2, 4, 6, 8, 10].includes(e.range.columnStart) && sheet.getName() == 'Valencia') {
    // Get the new quantity
    var newQuantity = e.value;
      
    // Log the new quantity
    console.log('New quantity in doSecondThing_: ' + newQuantity);
       
    // Calculate the ratio of new quantity to original quantity of the changed ingredient
    var recipeIndex = Math.floor(e.range.columnStart / 2) - 1;
    var ratio = newQuantity / originalQuantities[recipeIndex][e.range.rowStart - 4];  // Adjusted for the new row start
        
    // Get the range of cells with the quantities
    var startColumn = String.fromCharCode(66 + recipeIndex * 2);  // 66 is the ASCII value for 'B'
    var quantityRange = sheet.getRange(startColumn + "4:" + startColumn + "8");  // Adjusted for the new row start and end
        
    // Get the values of the cells in the range
    var quantities = quantityRange.getValues();
        
    // Loop through each quantity
    for (var i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
       // Update the quantity based on the ratio and the original quantity
       quantities[i][0] = originalQuantities[recipeIndex][i] * ratio;
    }
        
    // Update the cells in the range with the new quantities
    quantityRange.setValues(quantities);
  }
}

If I edit the cells from row 4 and below, no error occurs on top of that cell. I tried logging it, but the error is:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
'getA1Notation')
    at doFirstThing_(Script1:12:61) at onEdit(Main:2:3)


Modification points:

About your 1st issue I get #NUM! error if I edit the cells in row 2 and 3. Error will be in the corresponding row below that certain edited cell., when I saw your showing script, in the function doSecondThing_, when the 2nd row is edited, e.range.rowStart  is 2. And, e.range.rowStart - 4 of var ratio = newQuantity / originalQuantities[recipeIndex][e.range.rowStart - 4]; is -2. By this, such an issue occurs. In your script, also I guess that it is required to consider the length of each element of originalQuantities. When it is supposed that your showing script is the same as your expected result, in this case, from your script, the editable rows are row 4 to row 8 at the function doSecondThing_.
I think that the reason for your 2nd issue of TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getA1Notation') is due to that e.range is undefined. But, in your script, when you directly run onEdit, e is undefined. By this, an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source') occurs at var spreadsheet = e.source; of doFirstThing_. And, when the cell is edited, e has the event object, and the property range has the value. So, e.range.getA1Notation() works. From this situation, I couldn't understand the situation e.range is undefined. By the way, if you installed onEdit function as the OnChange trigger, such an error like TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getA1Notation') occurs because of no property range in the event object e. But, I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, this is just my guess.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification? Please modify doSecondThing_ as follows.
From:
if ([2, 4, 6, 8, 10].includes(e.range.columnStart) && sheet.getName() == 'Valencia') {

To:
if ([2, 4, 6, 8, 10].includes(e.range.columnStart) && sheet.getName() == 'Valencia' && e.range.rowStart - 4 >= 0 && e.range.rowStart - 4 < originalQuantities[0].length) {


By this modification, even when row 2 is edited, no error occurs at the function doSecondThing_.
From your showing script, I supposed that the length of each element of originalQuantities is the same. Please be careful about this.

Note:

In this modification, I supposed that the main process in your showing script works fine for your expected result. Please be careful about this.


Thank you. This worked. I was really tired last night. Can't notice those errors.

@Chase To Be Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
